# Как правильно пишется: рЕп или рЭп?

Tags: грамматика

Иногда вижу, что при написании слова "рэп" (которое относится к стилю хип-хоп-музыки) другие яростно пишут, что правильно "реп", при этом не могут объяснить **почему**. Но мы же не пишем "мер" (мэр), "сер" (сэр), хоть и пишем "флЕшка".

Хотелось бы узнать, как на данный момент правильно и почему?

Answer (score 1):

В отличие от имён собственных, для прочих слов правила транскрипции с английского (а они ещё и менялись во времени) не обязательны (если судить по результатам заимствований) но в некоторых случаях на них ориентироваться полезно. В этом примере при "е" слово совпадало бы по написанию с родительным падежом мн. числа слова **репа**, в то время как по транслитерации из **rap** в сочетании с английским произношением по тем правилам выходит "**э**", причём так записываются и другие заимствованные слова из трёх букв (вы привели такие); аналогия же с *русским* "зек" выглядит здесь неубедительно. "Флешка" - слово неформальное (ср. "фотка"), и его написание могло закрепиться *стихийно*, как и "флешмоб", хотя английский корень при обратной транскрипции восстановился бы не во flash (вспышка) а во flesh (мясная плоть).

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке, на самом деле, фонема /æ/ передаётся именно через "е", а не через "э", и дело тут не в английском, а в том, что русский внедрил в себя множество подобных слов тюркского происхождения, где латиницей (а порой и кириллицей) писалась буква "ә" (так называемая "шва"). В результате этому же правилу сегодня следуют все односложные слова, заимствованные из английского, например: треш, трек, стейк, секс, рейд и др.

Однако имеются исключения, наличие которых вызвано тем, что их написание через "е" привело бы к конфузу с уже существующими в русском словами именно русского происхождения. Таким образом мы пишем:

- "рэп" вместо "реп", иначе создаётся конфуз со словом "репа".
- "сэр" вместо "сер", иначе создаётся конфуз со словом "сера".
- "пэр" вместо "пер", иначе создаётся конфуз со словом "пера" (от "перо").
- "мэр" вместо "мер", иначе создаётся конфуз со словом "мера".

И так далее.

Comment: В словах *trash, track, steak, reid* и *sex* три разных звука (в некоторых дифтонга), так что подобны нашему примеру лишь первые два.